# File size is zero bytes on uploading image on google cloud storage --- nodejs?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage

This is my code for

```
const fs = require("fs");
const uuidv4 = require("uuid/v4");
const {Storage} = require("@google-cloud/storage");
const CLOUD_BUCKET = "priomark";
const storage = new Storage({
    projectId: 'priomark-v3',
    keyFilename: '../myapp/service.json'
})
const bucket = storage.bucket(CLOUD_BUCKET);

function upload(filess,cb) {
   var options = {
       metadata: {
          contentType: filess.mimeType
        }
   };
var file = filess;
var gcsname = uuidv4() + file.name;
// console.log(file.type)
var files = bucket.file(gcsname);
const blod = files.createWriteStream(options);
blod.on('error',(err)=>{
    console.log(err);
})

blod.on('finish', ()=>{
    console.log("file Uploaded",gcsname);
    cb(gcsname);
})

blod.end(file.buffer);
}

module.exports = {upload:upload};
```

Now code is working file is uploading but size of file is zero and on downloading its opening as a text file.
Please Help

Comment: did you find out why the file size is 0 ? i have the same problem

Comment: No not a clue have you found any solution

Comment: i did find a solution to my problem.. it was simply that we create the file but we don't write anything in it. I do the following : `const remoteWriteStream = bucket.file("path/to/new/file/newFile.wav").createWriteStream({contentType: 'audio/wav'})` and afterwards i add the content by applying a method that takes stream.Writable as an argument and write in it. For my case i used `ffmpeg().pipe()`

Comment: ohh that was so easy

Comment: @tarunjoshi Hi! Can you post the missing code? I'm dealing with the same problem