# Firebase storage uploads always have 0 bytes in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

Im trying to upload files to my google cloud storage using TypeScript and the NodeJS Firebase library, every time I attempt to create and write to a file it **creates** it but it always ends up with 0 bytes...

here is my code...

```
downloadFile(url:string, _path?:string):{dest: string, file: fs.WriteStream}{
    const dest: string = _path||path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'temp', `${uuid()}.temp`);
    console.log(dest);
    const file = fs.createWriteStream(dest);
    http.get(url, function(response) {
        response.pipe(file);
        file.on('finish', () => {
            file.close();
        });
    });
    return {dest, file};
}
downloadFileToStorage(url: string, filename: string) {
    const dest: string = this.downloadFile(url).dest;
    const ext: string = filename.split('.').splice(-1)[0];
    const src = fs.readFileSync(dest);
    const file = storage.file(filename);
    const stream = file.createWriteStream({
        metadata: {
            contentType: mimetypes[ext]
        }
    });
    stream.on('error', err => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
    stream.on('finish', () => {
        console.log('Finished!');
    });
    stream.end(src);
}
```

I call this function in my express app (its in the run function for test purposes)

```js
app.listen(process.env.PORT||8080, async () => {
    console.log(
        utils.downloadFileToStorage(
            'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png', 
            'bruv.png'
        ));
    console.log(`Up and ready to go on port ${process.env.PORT||8080}`);
});
```

this is my console afterwards...
[image: console]

and this is my Firebase Storage...
[image: firebase storage]

I've tried a lot of things and looked at a lot of other questions on this... the only way it seems to write anything is if i turn on gzip, and when i do and to get those files back, the completely corrupted, they dont even appear on google cloud itself.

if you know how to fix this please help!
thanks!

Comment: Hi @Artrix this is an indication that actually the file is not being uploaded, but only the name being used to create an empty file in the bucket. Considering that, could you please take a look at these two similar cases [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52616023/file-size-is-zero-bytes-on-uploading-image-on-google-cloud-storage-nodejs) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55448688/google-cloud-storage-php-uploaded-files-are-at-0-bytes) and check if they help you? They are not using the exactly framework you are, but the logic to read the file and upload it should help you.

Comment: Hey @gso_gabriel i looked at the NodeJS one and i didn't see anything that they did that i didn't

Comment: For me, it seems pretty much related to the `stream` part. As this other [case](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/2015), a `readStream` is used to check and read the file data, to be able to write on it - as indicated in the official [API](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#createReadStream). Considering that, could you please give it a try changing the way you are reading/downloading your file, before uploading it to Cloud Storage?

Comment: @gso_gabriel Ill try a write stream but the function that im using to download files is download is working 100% fine. So your basically just saying that instead of ```js
fs.readFileSync(dest);
```

i should do ```js
fs.readWriteSync(dest);
``` ?

Comment: Sure, I understand your point, it's more to try a different solution, as the `stream` part is in both functions. Besides that, as you if you check this other case and per the API, you maybe need to use both, depending on which situation you are. So, changing the way you are doing might fix your case.